# Randomly Changing Images from an Array of Images

Tags: jquery, html, image, random

The title basically says it all.

I am trying to change an image to a random image from an array of images (hope that makes sense lol).

How can I create an array of images and then have the image change to a random image when something is clicked?

```
<h1>These are just placeholders</h1>
<p>I just want these images to randomly change to an image from an array of images each time they are shown (when "display" isn't "none")</p>
<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/11/21/07/30/icon-214446_960_720.jpg" class="newsAD"></img>
<img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/11/21/07/30/according-to-214445_960_720.jpg" class="newsAD"></img>

<style>
    .newsAD {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      background: skyblue;
      cursor: default;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
function changeImageToRandomImage() {
 // something here that changes image to random image from array of images
}
</script>
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/d1ec07p2/5/)

Comment: when display isn't none?

Comment: Like in CSS. ('display: none')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a situation you would store images somewhere and then store their paths in the array and call them like such:

HTML

```
<img onclick="changeImageToRandomImage()" id="image" src="img/image_0.jpg">
```

JavaScript

```
function changeImageToRandomImage() {
   images = ['img/image_1.jpg', 'img/image_2.jpg','img/image_3.jpg','img/image_4.jpg'];

   var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
   document.getElementById('image').src= random;

}
```

Comment: Given this, you can then change your function to change images randomly based on time (slideshow style), or `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://www.javascriptworld.com/js6e/chap4-10.html) shows how to do that with a regular (non-Ajax) web page where the images are listed in an array and the random number generated is used to selected a specific image from it. Another approach is to implement the random image selection on the server side (e.g. NodeJS) and use the same Ajax call on the client to trigger the server selector logic.